# Go through files in given directory with python, read each file line by line and remove first and last string in the line and save updated file

Tags: python, string, parsing, txt

So I have some .txt files inside of directory. Each .txt file contains some paths like:

```
'C:\d\folder\project\folder\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Module.c'
'C:\d\folder\project\folder\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Module2.c'
'C:\d\folder\project\folder\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Module3.c'
```

I need just some small function that will go through each line of each file inside of a dir and remove there ', so only clear path is left like:

```
     C:\d\folder\project\folder\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Module.c
     C:\d\folder\project\folder\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Module2.c
     C:\d\folder\project\folder\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Module3.c
```

My code at the moment is:

```
for filename in files:
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read().split('\n')
        for line in content:
            if line.startswith('')and line.endswith(''):
                remove('')
```

Please assist!

SOLUTION:

I have managed to find a solution with a bit different approach:

```
for filename in files:
    f = open(filename, 'rt')
    filedata = f.read()
    filedata = filedata.replace("'","")
    f.close()
    f = open(filename, 'wt')
    f.write(filedata)
    f.close()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

python has a hirarchy to strings `'`, `"`, `""` and so on so you can wrap a uptick into quotes for a split. Since we have the first element `''` before the tick the second is your path

```
line.split("'")[1]
```

Edit: If i understood you correctly you want this

```
for filename in files:
    paths = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read().split('\n')
        for line in content:
            paths.append(line.split("'")[1])
    file.close()
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(paths)
    file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you please provide full code also with writing file, i tried with:for filename in files:
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read().split('\n')
        for line in content:
            line.split("'")[1]
        file.close()
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        file.write(line)
        file.close()
but it does not work

Comment: can you update this in your question? that makes the code readable^^ Also not 100% sure what you mean

Comment: ahhh I have managed to find a solution with a different much easier way, thanks anyway I understood what you meant, I will update with solution!

Answer (score 0):

Soo I just did bit different approach and managed to find a solution:

```
for filename in files:
    f = open(filename, 'rt')
    filedata = f.read()
    filedata = filedata.replace("'","")
    f.close()
    f = open(filename, 'wt')
    f.write(filedata)
    f.close()
```

Thanks guys anyway!